# Flutter Dio Nothing downloaded on device but OK on emulator

Tags: android, flutter

Here is my part of code :

```
            onPressed: () async {
              Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
                Permission.storage,
              ].request();

              if (statuses[Permission.storage]!.isGranted) {
                Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
                String savename = "file.gpx";

                String savePath = "${dir.path}/$savename";
                print(savePath);

                try {
                  await Dio().download(fileurl, savePath,
                      onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
                    if (total != -1) {
                      print(
                          "${(received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%");
                    }
                  });
                  print("File is saved to download folder.");
                } on DioError catch (e) {
                  print(e.message);
                }
                // }
              } else {
                print("No permission to read and write.");
              }
```

it works on emulator and correctly download the file and print

```
I/flutter ( 8396): /storage/emulated/0/Download/file.gpx
I/flutter ( 8396): 100%
I/flutter ( 8396): File is saved to download folder.
```

but when i press the same button on my android device (after accept permission storage) there is no file in download directory

Comment: Use path_provider: ^2.0.11 to get Downloads folder directory rather than directly statically putting downloads directory (getApplicationDocumentsDirectory)

Comment: but can't get download directory path with path_provider on android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() from path_provider package to detect application directory for saving the downloaded file

Comment: but can't get download directory path with path_provider on android